# Sequelize: Problem with dobule $ in JSON_EXTRACT

Tags: mysql, typescript, sequelize.js

I'm having a problem with the double dollar in query with JSON_EXTRACT.

My query:

```
const user = await UserModel.findOne({
    where: where(fn('JSON_EXTRACT', col('config'), '$.type'), type),
    attributes: ['id'],
})
```

the result looks like this:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(`config`, '$$.type') = 'admin' LIMIT 1;
```

The problem is in double **$$**. Is this a problem specific or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: could you describe a bit more explicitly what is the specific problem? I don't quite follow.

Comment: Also, if you are inspecting a json stored in a field to filter results, you may find it better to extract that element to its own column. It will also help with performance because it allows you to add indexes.

Comment: Add youor error log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sequelize.where(
  sequelize.fn('JSON_EXTRACT', 
    sequelize.col('config'), 
    sequelize.literal(`'$.type'`)
  ),
  type
)
```

Related Issue: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11533

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it